# Notify About New Tweets

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to make a simple script which tells me when a Twitter account has a new tweet.

```
import urllib

def CurrentP(array, string):
    count = 0
    for a_ in array:
        if a_ == string:
            return count
        count = count + 1

twitters = ["troyhunt", "codinghorror"]
last = []
site = "http://twitter.com/"

for twitter in twitters:
    source = site+twitter
    for line in urllib.urlopen(source):
        if line.find(twitter+"/status") != -1:
            id = line.split('/')[3]
            if id != last[CurrentP(twitters,twitter)]:
                print "[+] New tweet + " + twitter
            last[CurrentP(twitters,twitter)] = id
```

But get this error when I try to run the script

```
File "twitter.py", line 16 in ?
for line in urllib.urlopen(source):
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You're probably not getting the file like object out of urlopen you expect. Can you add in a test for what `urllib.urlopen(source)` actually is?

Answer (score 1):

Web Scraping is not the most economical way of retrieving data, `Twitter` does provides it own [API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public), which returns data in nice `JSON` format which is very easy to parse and get the relevant inforation, The nice thing is that there are many python libraries available which do the same for you , like [Tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy), making the data extraction as simple as this [example](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/examples/streaming.py).

Comment: This answer tells about Tweepy, but doesn't answer the OPs request to learn how to notify about new tweets on an  account with Python